# Replace last element of a list if there is somewhere a 0 in the list

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I have the following list of lists:

```
l = {{5,6,0,8,5,9}, {8,4,4,3,5,8}, {9,4,3,2,5,7}}
```

now if there is a 0 in one of the lists *Mathematica* should replace the last element in the list with 0 like this:

```
l1 = {{5,6,0,8,5,0}, {8,4,4,3,5,8}, {9,4,3,2,5,7}}
```

the `l1` should be my output. I have no idea how is can do this, I hope someone can help.

Comment: `l /. x_ /; MemberQ[x, 0] :> ReplacePart[x, -1 -> 0]`

Comment: @JasonB Dang it! I was 15 seconds too late. -- Here's an alternative: `l1 = l /. a: {___, 0, ___ } :> ReplacePart[a, -1 -> 0]`

Comment: ReplacePart is not necessary `l1 /. {a___, 0, b___, _} -> {a, 0, b, 0}`. I see no reason for `RuleDelayed` either?

Comment: @Coolwater `RuleDelayed` is standard if you are using variables in both sides of `Rule`; it prevents naming conflicts, etc. For instance, `a = 3; {1, 2, 3} /. a_Integer -> a` does not work. One could clear variables prior to running `ReplaceAll`, but writing `Clear` every time there is `/.` is too inconvenient!

Comment: @Coolwater Nice method, but heed JHM's warning.

Comment: In my opinion, best answer in terms of elegance, clarity, maintainability is that of CoolWater-JasonB, l /. {a___, 0, b___, _} :> {a, 0, b, 0}. Which one is the fastest and why ?

Answer (score 14):

```
l[[All, -1]] = l[[All, -1]] Times @@@ Unitize@l ; l
```

or, better (thanks: @Mr.Wizard):

```
l[[All, -1]] *= Times @@@ Unitize@l ; l
```

> {{5, 6, 0, 8, 5, 0}, {8, 4, 4, 3, 5, 8}, {9, 4, 3, 2, 5, 7}}

**Update:** Per @JasonB's comment, if you want to create a new list without changing `l`, you can use

```
Module[{l2 = #}, l2[[All, -1]] *= Times @@@ Unitize@l2 ; l2] &@l
```

or

```
ReplacePart[l, { i_, -1} :> Times @@ Unitize@l[[i]]]
```

to get

> {{5, 6, 0, 8, 5, 0}, {8, 4, 4, 3, 5, 8}, {9, 4, 3, 2, 5, 7}}

Comment: Using `*=` is shorter:  `l[[All, -1]] *= Times @@@ Unitize@l; l`

Comment: @Mr.W, yes, thank you!

Comment: Nice!  If you want to do this without changing the definition of the original list, `ReplacePart[#, -1 -> Times @@ Unitize@#] & /@ l`

Comment: This one's elegant (+1), but (possibly) trails slightly behind ciao's method since IIRC, MMA doesn't have an efficient built-in for the product of a list of numbers in the same manner that it does for the sum (`Total`).

Answer (score 12):

S/B quick (assuming non-negative list members as in OP):

```
Module[{ll = #}, ll[[Pick[Range@Length@ll, Min /@ ll, 0], -1]] = 0; ll] &
```

If negative members allowed, small performance impact:

```
Module[{ll = #}, ll[[Pick[Range@Length@ll, Min /@ Abs[ll], 0], -1]] = 0; ll] &
```

Comment: You always have a method that is at least three orders of magnitude faster than what I think of, and usually completely inscrutable to me lol.  Nice

Comment: @JasonB: Habit, from days of limited memory/limited CPU assembly programming. Downside for me: I'll revisit old quick-n-dirty, not commented code of mine and do a "WTF is this doing and how???"...

Comment: Count on ciao to come up with something completely illegible, but be sure, it'll never unpack arrays or copy them with O(n) complexity. +1

Answer (score 7):

kglr's answer is really clever, but I'll just post this as well.

```
l /. x_ /; MemberQ[x, 0] :> ReplacePart[x, -1 -> 0]
```

or a slightly shorter variant using patterns instead of of `MemberQ`, from JHM.

```
l /. a : {___, 0, ___} :> ReplacePart[a, -1 -> 0]
```

Shorter still, you use patterns instead of `ReplacePart`, from Coolwater

```
l /. {a___, 0, b___, _} :> {a, 0, b, 0}
```

Comment: a variant I like: `l /. a:{b___, _} /; MemberQ[a, 0] :> {b, 0}`.

Comment: @JasonB I like your ReplaceAll answers because one can learn more about the essence of programming in Mathematica, i.e. rules and patterns and in my opinion they add clarity and code maintainability. In the spirit of rules transformation, kglr and rcollyer answers work fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

A bit differently than in the answers so far. Mapping on sublists:

```
If[MemberQ[#, 0] && Last[#] =!= 0, Most[#]~Append~0, #] & /@ l
```

Pattern matching:

```
l /. {pre__, _} /; MemberQ[{pre}, 0] :> {pre, 0}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what saves more time - cutting on the unnecessary `Append` if `Last[#] === 0` or dropping the `Last[#] =!= 0` test.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP It doesn't save space but I think the additional test saves time. It's rarely used and when it's, it surely has to beat construction.

Answer (score 3):

Just an alternative

```
MapAt[0 &, l, {#, -1} & @@@ Position[l, 0, {2}]]
```

or

```
ReplacePart[l, {#, -1} -> 0 & @@@ Position[l, 0, {2}]]
```